# Laravel Model Relationship or Adonis Model Relationship

Tags: php, typescript, laravel, model-view-controller, model

My question is to know if it is possible to create a relationship between content from a single table by dividing the content with another model either with a one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many relationship or others.

Let me clarify my question more. I have one `user` table that is divided by roles, that is the users will be inserted on the `user` table in two different roles, so it means from all the users found on the `user` table some of them have a "consumer" role and the rest have a "maker" role. I want to know if I can connect users from the `user` table with the "consumer" role with a `Post` model and the users from the `user` table with the "maker" role with the `Pricing` model. Is that possible?

I tried to find the solution, but all the solutions I look for on the Laravel documentation or Adonis documentation to create a connection between models is not quite exactly what I am looking for. Maybe I am missing something or it is not possible. I would appreciate if I got a response both from the Laravel and Adonis perspective if possible.